# How to make migrations in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I need to create the db and make migrations for it. I found out how to do it in this video. I do everything like in that video, but, unfortunately, it doesn't work (When I run app.py db migrate, it writes to me that no changes in schema detected, and in db file, linked to it is only one table alembic_version), and I don't know why. How to fix this bug?

> [[Link for that video]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAOfjPuVby0&t=326s&ab_channel=PrettyPrinted)

My models.py file

```
from app import db
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.id)

class Location(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Location {}>'.format(self.id)

class AnnouncementType(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<AnnouncementType {}>'.format(self.id)

class Announcement(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    authorid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text,nullable=False)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.String(11),nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('Location.id'),nullable=False)
    announcement_type = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('AnnouncementType.id') ,nullable=False)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Announcement {}>'.format(self.id)
```

My app.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect 
from config import Config 
from flask_script import Manager 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from flask_migrate import Migrate,MigrateCommand 
from datetime import datetime



    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///lab.db'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)
    manager = Manager(app)
    manager.add_command('db',MigrateCommand)
    
    @app.route('/')
    def start():
        return "Empty page"
    
    
    @app.route('/api/v1/hello-world-16')
    def greeting():
        return "Hello World 16"
    
    
    @app.route('/film', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def film():
       return "<h1>Old version</h1>"
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        manager.run()
```

Comment: Did you run the init command first `python app.py db init` ?

Comment: Yes. It created folder with migrations.